# Chart labels are crowded

Tags: reactjs, charts, react-chartjs-2

[image]

I do not want to show all the labels just show some.

Its mostly handled by https://react-chartjs-2.js.org/ itself.

But it still looks crowded, I do not want to change the orientation, want to keep them horizontal.

I was trying to parse chart data and display limited data, but its not proper solution, depending upon width available labels should increase and decrease and should not be crowded.

I am working on dynamic data and there can be thousand of labels.

Please give some direction for the solution.